# Hard drive partition and updating trouble

Tags: linux-mint, apt, gpg

I'm new to linux and am using Linux Mint 15 Olivia. I am running it alongside windows 7 and I want to increase the size of my current linux hard drive partition. I read somewhere that I should install the GParted package, but I get this error:

```
$ sudo apt-get install gparted
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree 
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package gparted
```

And then someone told me I should try entering:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
```

And then I keep getting this at the bottom of the installation log:

> W: GPG error: http://archive.canonical.com raring Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 40976EAF437D05B5 Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key

Then I tried running:

> sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com 40976EAF437D05B5

and get the output:

> Executing: gpg --ignore-time-conflict --no-options --no-default-keyring --secret-keyring /tmp/tmp.q0RYkOedsz --trustdb-name /etc/apt//trustdb.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --primary-keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com 40976EAF437D05B5
>   gpg: requesting key 437D05B5 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
>   gpg: key 437D05B5: "Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key " not changed
>   gpg: Total number processed: 1
>   gpg:              unchanged: 1

And when I run:

> for f in /etc/apt/sources.list.d /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*; do echo "$f:"; cat "$f"; done

I get:

http://pastebin.com/eaDM7ive

I already changed the softer source to my local mirror.
As I said I am very new to all of this. Any ideas about what could be wrong?

Comment: Please post the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: # deb http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu raring-getdeb apps games

Comment: Is this the _only_ line in the `sources.list` file? If that's the case, take a look at the second item in [12 things to do after installing Linux Mint 15 Olivia](http://dikkiisdesktop.wordpress.com/2013/07/15/12-things-to-do-after-installing-linux-mint-15-olivia-xfce/) You need to add the software sources before running `apt-get update` or `apt-get install gparted`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the repository's key to your key list. Run this command:

```
sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com 40976EAF437D05B5
```

Your next problem is that you seem to have commented out the single repository listed in your `/etc/apt/sources.list`. This file contains a list of repositories that will be searched for available software. Any line that begins with `#` is ignored.

So, open that file with an editor (`sudo pluma /etc/apt/sources.list`) and make it look like this:

```
deb http://packages.linuxmint.com/ olivia main upstream import
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ raring partner
deb http://packages.medibuntu.org/ raring free non-free
```

Then, save the file and try and install `gparted` again:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install gparted
```

Comment: I ran the command you suggested but I still got the same error when I tried to run >sudo apt-get update..

Comment: @user2789331 Could you update your question with the exact command you ran (`sudo apt-key ...`) and the exact error message received?

Comment: @user2789331 also, please [edit] your question and post the output of `for f in /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.d/*; do echo "$f:"; cat "$f"; done`.

Comment: @user2789331 I believe #terdon meant `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`.

Comment: @JosephR.  I ran the modified command and get an output with a lot of url's but the site does not allow me to post more than 2, since I'm new to stackexchange. Are these links relevant to the problem? And thanks for your help

Comment: @user2789331 You can paste the output on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) (or similar) and link to it in your question

Comment: You shouldn't be using the Ubuntu archive in mint; gparted should be in mint's repositories.  Also raring is end of life.

Comment: @psusi mot true, mint needs and expects the Ubuntu repos. That looks like the default sources.list

Comment: @terdon, they should have their own where they import most packages from Ubuntu, and modify some, just like Ubuntu does with Debian.

Comment: @psusi see [here](http://blog.linuxmint.com/?p=215): "The Linux Mint repositories contain all the software developed by us, imported by us or in a more general way, all the software we decided to maintain. " Everything else they take directly from Ubuntu's repos, you cannot install a full system from the Mint repos alone. Unlike Ubuntu with Debian, Mint has simply added some stuff over the basic Ubuntu, they have not repackages the whole thing. For example, Mint's [repos](http://packages.linuxmint.com/list.php?release=Petra#import) don't even have `kernel-headers`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what was wrong with `apt-get`, but using the Software Manager fixed this for me.